# sqlite3 doesn't accept spacing in text (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I'm using [this](http://www.appcoda.com/sqlite-database-ios-app-tutorial/) tutorial to create an app for iOS with a sqlite3 database. However, instead of having name, lastname and age; I have name and the current date.

I use NSDate to get the current date and I put it in a UILabel instead of a UITextField.

Now, when I press save, I get "Syntax error". I've tried using the current year and it works because it's an integer even though the column in the table is set to "text". A date with spacing like "16 Feb 2017" doesn't seem to work either because it has spacing in it.

I want to be able to save it in this format: **16 Feb 2017**.

Thanks!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];

//Get the date today.
NSString *dateToday = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

self.txtFirstname.delegate = self;
[_txtAge setText:dateToday];

- (IBAction)saveInfo:(id)sender {
    // Prepare the query string.
    // If the recordIDToEdit property has value other than -1, then create an update query. Otherwise create an insert query.
    NSString *query;
    if (self.recordIDToEdit == -1) {
        query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into peopleInfo values(null, '%@', %@)", self.txtFirstname.text, self.txtDate.text];
    }
    else{
        query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"update peopleInfo set firstname='%@', date=%@ where peopleInfoID=%d", self.txtFirstname.text, self.txtDate.text, self.recordIDToEdit];
    }


    // Execute the query.
    [self.dbManager executeQuery:query];

    // If the query was successfully executed then pop the view controller.
     if (self.dbManager.affectedRows != 0) {
        NSLog(@"Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = %d", self.dbManager.affectedRows);

        // Inform the delegate that the editing was finished.
        [self.delegate editingInfoWasFinished];

        // Pop the view controller.
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Could not execute the query.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Text data type should accept text with space. Just delete existing version app from device or simulator and try again.

Comment: I tried that, but I just get the same: 
2017-02-16 05:32:48.953091 SQLite3DBSample[627:104914] near "February": syntax error
2017-02-16 05:32:48.953236 SQLite3DBSample[627:104914] Could not execute the query.

Comment: Send me empty DB if you can

Comment: CREATE TABLE peopleInfo(peopleInfoID integer primary key, firstname text, date text);

Comment: if you have declared datatype is **TEXT** fire query like  `INSERT INTO peopleInfo (peopleInfoID, peopleInfoID, date) VALUES (1, 'test', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS ') `// Set date format what you wants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put `'` around the date format specifier `%@` to `'%@'`as below

```
if (self.recordIDToEdit == -1) {
    query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into peopleInfo values(null, '%@', '%@')", self.txtFirstname.text, self.txtDate.text];
}
else{
    query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"update peopleInfo set firstname='%@', date='%@' where peopleInfoID=%d", self.txtFirstname.text, self.txtDate.text, self.recordIDToEdit];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add text value within ''.
EX.

```
query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into peopleInfo (peopleInfoID,firstname,date) values (1, 'user name', '16 FEB 2016')"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

> insert into peopleInfo (peopleInfoID,firstname,date) values (1,
>   'cuckoo', '16 FEB 2016')

It's working for me!